# Github action check if a file already exists

Tags: file, github, yaml, action, github-actions

I have the following git action which allows me to download an image.

I have to make sure if the file already exists to skip the "Commit file" and the "Push changes"

How can I check if the file already exists if it already exists nothing is done.

```yaml
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  
name: Scrape File
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Check out current commit
     
      - name: Url
        run: |
         URL=$(node ./action.js)
         echo $URL
         echo "URL=$URL" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - uses: suisei-cn/actions-download-file@v1
        id: downloadfile
        name: Download the file
        with:
          url: ${{ env.URL }}
          target: assets/
      - run: ls -l 'assets/'
          
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
         git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
         git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
         git add .
         git commit -m "Add changes" -a
         
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
         github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
         branch: ${{ github.ref }}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use Github Actions built-in `hashFiles` function for this.
From the docs:

> Returns a single hash for the set of files that matches the path pattern. You can provide a single path pattern or multiple path patterns separated by commas. (...) If the path pattern does not match any files, this returns an empty string.
>
> See docs  for details: [docs.github.com](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#hashfiles)

So you can do like this:

```
  - name: Commit files
    if: ${{ hashFiles('assets/') != '' }}
    run: |
     git config ...
```

This won't work for checking directories though, as `hashFiles` will return empty string for empty directories.

Credits for the solution goes to Peter Bengtsson's blog: [peterbe.com/plog](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-run-workflow-step-if-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 11):

There are a few options here - you can go directly with bash and do something like this:

```
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    #file exists
fi
```

or use one of the existing actions like this:

```
- name: Check file existence
  id: check_files
  uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v1
  with:
    files: "assets/${{ env.URL }}"

- name: File exists
  if: steps.check_files.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
  run: echo "It exists !"
```

Comment: The problem is that `$ {{env.URL}}` is a url like:
`https: //name.com / .. etc ../ nameFile.ext`

The name of the file saved in the assets folder is instead `nameFile.ext`

Comment: Than you just need to adapt it to your needs and provide local file check

Answer (score 1):

#### WARNING: Linux (and maybe MacOS) only solution ahead!

I was dealing with a very similar situation some time earlier and developed a method to not just check for added files, but also will be useful if you wanted to check for modified or deleted files or directories as well.

---

#### Warning:

This solution works only if the file is added/modified/deleted in git repository.

---

#### Introduction:

The command `git status --short` will return list of untracked, , deleted and modified files. For example:-

```
 D deleted_foo
 M modified_foo
?? untracked_dir_foo/
?? untracked_file_foo
A  tracked_n_added_foo
```

*Note that we run the same command as `git status -s`.*

#### Understanding `git status -s` output:

When you read the output, you will see some lines in this form:

```
** filename
** dirname/
```

Note that here `**` represent the first word of the line (ones like `D`, `??` etc.).

Here is a summary of all `**` in the lines:

| `**` | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `D` | File/dir has been deleted. |
| `M` | File/dir has been modified. |
| `??` | File/dir has been added but not tracked using `git add [FILENAME]`. |
| `A` | File/dir has been added and also tracked using `git add [FILENAME]`. |

**NOTE: Take care of the spaces!** Using, for example, `M` instead of  `M` in the following solution will not work as expected!

---

#### Solution:

##### Shell part of solution:

We can `grep` the output of `git status -s` to check whether a file/dir was added/modified/deleted.

The shell part of the solution goes like this:

```bash
if git status -s | grep -x "** [FILENAME]"; then
  # Do whatever you wanna on match
else
  # Do whatever you wanna on no-match
fi
```

**Note:** Get desired `**` from the table above and replace `[FILENAME]` with filename.

For example, to check whether a file named `foo` was modified, use:

```
git status -s | grep -x " M foo"
```

**Explanation:** We use `git status -s` to get the output and pipe the output to `grep`. We also use command line option `-x` with `grep` so as to match whole line.

##### Workflow part of solution:

A very simple solution will go like this:

```yml
...
- name: Check for file
  id: file_check
  run: |
    if git status -s | grep -x "** [FILENAME]"; then
      echo "check_result=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    else
      echo "check_result=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    fi
...
- name: Run dependent step
  if: steps.file_check.outputs.check_result == 'true'
  run: |
    # Do whatever you wanna do on file found to be
    # added/modified/deleted, based on what you set '**' to
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
if [ -d "directory"]; then echo dir exists && echo ok; else echo no dir; fi
```