Run a Github workflow step if a file exists even if the previous step failed
I'm aware about the "quirk" that if no status check function is used, success() is applied.
I'm also ware of that hashFiles can be used to check if a file exists.
I want to run a step entirely based on whether or not a file exists, regardless of previous steps' success or failure.
The workflow below shows all the conditions I'd hope to control:

A file exists and the previous step succeeded.
A file does not exist and the previous step succeeded.
A file exists and the previous step failed.
A file does not exist and the previous step failed.

name: Mock

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  mock:
    name: Mock
    runs-on: [linux]

    steps:
      ########################################################################
      # Create a file, succeed, then check its existence.
      ########################################################################
      - name: Create mock-success.xml; exit 0
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }}
        run: |
          echo success > mock-success.xml
          cat mock-success.xml
          exit 0

        # NOTE: `hashFile` usage to test if a file exists is from
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081661/149506
      - name: mock-success.xml exists (should always run)
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && ${{ hashFiles('mock-success.xml') != '' }}
        run: |
          exit 0

        ########################################################################
        # Create a file, succeed, then check the existence of a nonsense file.
        ########################################################################
      - name: Create mock-success-2.xml; exit 0
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }}
        run: |
          echo success > mock-success-2.xml
          cat mock-success-2.xml
          exit 0

      - name: does-not-exist-success.xml exists (should never run)
        # SHOULD NOT RUN BUT DOES
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && ${{ hashFiles('does-not-exist-success.xml') != '' }}
        run: |
          exit 0

        ########################################################################
        # Create a file, fail, then check its existence.
        ########################################################################
      - name: Create mock-fail.xml; exit 1
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }}
        run: |
          echo fail > mock-fail.xml
          cat mock-fail.xml
          exit 1

      - name: mock-fail.xml exists (should always run)
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && ${{ hashFiles('mock-fail.xml') != '' }}
        run: |
          exit 0

        ########################################################################
        # Create a file, fail, then check the existence of a nonsense file.
        ########################################################################
      - name: Create mock-fail-2.xml; exit 1
        # This step runs as expected.
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }}
        run: |
          echo fail > mock-fail-2.xml
          cat mock-fail-2.xml
          exit 1

      - name: does-not-exist-fail.xml exists (should never run)
        # SHOULD NOT RUN BUT DOES
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && ${{ hashFiles('does-not-exist-fail.xml') != '' }}
        run: |
          exit 0

The workflow is behaving as if the hashFiles calls are not doing what I think they should, because all the steps run.
What is the correct way to run a step only if a file exists, regardless of previous steps' outcomes?
EDIT
I tried reducing the workflow to a single step:
name: Mock

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  mock:
    name: Mock
    runs-on: [linux]

    steps:
      - name: does-not-exist-success.xml exists (should never run)
        # SHOULD NOT RUN BUT DOES
        if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && ${{ hashFiles('does-not-exist-success.xml') != '' }}
        run: |
          exit 0

And this step runs every time, regardless of what comparison I put on hashFiles (== '' or != ''). If I replace the if with a simple if: false, the single step does not run, so somehow, my if is true, and I just don't get it.

I've tested the scenario where the file does not exist and a failure occur previously here, and it seems to work as expected. Did I miss something? workflow file

@GuiFalourd I'm not sure what your line !hashFiles('does-not-exist-fail.txt') != '' is doing; seems like you're noting a string.

I've updated the workflow file so that you can check the output of the whole expression. !hashFiles('does-not-exist-fail.txt') doesn't do anything on it own, however !hashFiles('does-not-exist-fail.txt') != '' actually returns the opposite of hashFiles('does-not-exist-fail.txt') != '' (I know it doesn't seem to work that way). Check the workflow run here

Turns out the entire if needs to be inside an ${{ }} block.
This evidently evaluates to true:
if: ${{ ! cancelled() }} && false

This correctly evaluates to false:
if: ${{ ! cancelled() && false }}

